# Symfony vendor bundle does not load config.yml

Tags: php, symfony

I wrote many Symfony 2.2 bundles. At the begening, they were in the src/ directory. For a new project, I moved them to the vendor directory.

They need to be configured by using config.yml setting file. The Dependency Injection Configuration file of the main bundle validates de config.yml structure but does not load the settings: it loads the default configuration…

vendor/myFirm/src/Trinity/Bundle/ContentManagerBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php https://wall.deblan.org/x1805/php/1/configuration-php

vendor/myFirm/src/Trinity/Bundle/ContentManagerBundle/DependencyInjection/TrinityContentManagerExtension.php https://wall.deblan.org/x1806/php/1/TrinityContentManagerExtension-php

app/config/config.yml wall.deblan.org/x1808/yaml/0/

When I put a var_dump($config) TrinityContentManagerExtension.php, I just have the default values set in Configuration.php.

Could you help me please?

PS: I don't have the same problem with the others.

Comment: how do your settings look in config.yml ? make sure you don't have a dublicate declaration overwriting them lateron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you don't have a dublicate declaration overwriting your settings.

If you have i.e. the following situation in your config.yml ...

```
namespace:
    setting1: value1
    setting2: value2
    # .. more settings

namespace: ~
```

... only the defaults will be loaded.

---

loading and validating configuration are two different tasks.

you can validate a completely different configuration while it's not being loaded afterwards.

configuration will only be loaded if it uses an alias matching an extension.

add [getAlias()](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Extension/Extension.php#L69) to your Extension in order to hardcode it...

```
public function getAlias()
{
   return 'trinity_content_manager';
}
```

... and make sure the Extension is properly loaded.

Comment: I just tried to put the getAlias method with no result. My extension should be loaded because the source code is exactly the same as the src/ of my other projet (svn inclusion).

Comment: if you comment out the bundle in your app/AppKernel.php but leave the configuration in config.yml ... does symfony throw the exception "There was no extension able to load trinity_content_manager" ?

Comment: Yes: « FileLoaderLoadException: Cannot import resource "[...] app/config/config.yml" from "[...] app/config/config_dev.yml" »

Comment: please provide which settings you have in config.yml - how they differ from the defaults.

Comment: Expected: https://wall.deblan.org/x180a/texte/0/
Result: https://wall.deblan.org/x180b/texte/0/

Comment: After many hours...the problem was very stupid: I had another trinity_content_manager in the config file.

Thank's for helping me!

Have a good day :)

Comment: [...] make sure you don't have a dublicate declaration overwriting [...] - my words , first comment :D I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Yep...I don't know why but I by passed the first part… (I should take more coffee). Thank a lot again ;)